# Can Apps be side-loaded rather than uploaded to the iOS app store?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

If I create a simple App, would it be possible for me to install it in any other devices without having to upload it to the Apple Store and wait for the reviewing process?

Comment: I'll assume you are not interested in jailbreaking your iOS device. That too allows you to install apps that are not signed which clearly would bypass the review and upload process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, however you will need to set up a provisioning profile and add each device you are installing you app on (you are allowed to provision 100 devices).

You do need to join the iOS Developers program for this to work ($99 per year).

Once you join the developer program you can set up your provisioning profile from the provisioning portal (https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) there is an Assistant to walk you through the process (which IMO is a PITA).

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, there a couple of ways this could be achieved.

- With a **Enterprise Developer Account**, you'll be able to *Archive* your App for **in-house** distribution, being eligible *any* device. Bear in mind that openly distributing your App this way will infringe Apple's agreement and your account could be suspended, as it's meant to be used for a company to distribute an App among its employees.
- With a *Regular* developer account you could send an **ad-Hoc**
  version of your App, which could be installed into any device
  which has been previously registered in your Developer Account. You'll only be able to register 100 devices, though.

With either account, you'll be able to *build* a version of your App in any device.

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/) Apple's list of their different Developer Programs.